# Powershell Script to restart Windows Service If it is Down and send email

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script which monitors the status of Windows services on multiple servers. Can someone help me with few modification where script checks the status and restarts the service if its not running? I would also like to send one consolidated email.

### Code Below

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\servers.txt 
$Servers | ForEach-Object { 
invoke-command -ComputerName $_ -Scriptblock {Get-Service W3SVC} 
}| Out-File C:\Result.txt
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: To determine the service state: Get-Service. To start a service Start-Service. To send an email Send-MailMessage. Read the help for those cmdlets, write some code, then post questions when you have specific issues that you can't figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified te script again and its working for me now.

```
#$Services=Get-content C:\Services.txt
$Servers=get-content C:\servers.txt
$SMPTServer = "smtp.ac.com"
$result = "The following service restarted:`n" # default output

$Servers|Foreach-Object{

$result += Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { # add output of scriptblock to $result
$CompName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Name
(Get-Service -Name Splunkd)|  #Get the services running on all servers
Where-Object{$_.Status -eq "Stopped"}| #Which status is equal stopped
Foreach-Object{
if($_.Status -eq "Stopped") 
     {
     Write-Output "`n -Service:- Splunkd is Down on Server $CompName - Service Splunkd on Server $CompName Restarted Successfully `n" # any action is added to output
     $_.(Start-Service Splunkd) #try to start
     #Start-Sleep -Seconds 60;  #wait one minute
     #$_.Refresh();  #refresh then service to update status

    }}}}

     if ($result -ne "The following service restarted:`n") { # If any action was taken send mail with $result
   send-mailmessage -to "xx@xx.com" -from "abc@bc.com" -subject "Splunkd Service Restarted Alert" -Body $result -SmtpServer $SMPTServer 
   }
```

Comment: Can anyone check above modified one. i need consolidated email consisting of multple servers that were services restarted.

Comment: This looks like it's either an edit to the question or another question with a different problem, since you don't seem to be at all sure it solves your problem.

Comment: I updated the script which resolves my problem of sending mail that's why i edited my own answer. Involving invoke command and kepping the results as string resolves it.